# Every self-complementary graph contains a Hamiltonian path.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

How to show that every self-complementary graph is traceable (contains a Hamiltonian path)?

Definitions:

[Self-complementary graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-complementary_graph)
[Hamiltonian-Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path)
[Traceable Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TraceableGraph.html)

Comment: Hi, could you give us some context? What do you know in graph theory? what have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Your source for the definition of “traceable” links to a pdf of a thesis by Ferrugia which contains a proof of the result you want. Also note that not all self-complementary graphs have Hamilton cycles - $P_4$ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the vertices of $G$ such that
$$d_1 \leq \ldots \leq d_n$$

Now, because $G$ is self-complementary, you can check that its vertices verify the following implication ($d_i$ correspondant to $d_{n+1-i}$ in its complementary):

$$\text{"} d_i \leq i-1 < \frac{n+1}{2} \ \Rightarrow\ d_{n+1-i} \geq n-i\text{"}.$$

Let $G'$ be a graph built from $G$, adding one vertex $u$, connected to all vertices of $G$. Then the vertices of $G'$ verify

$$ d_i \leq i < \frac{n}{2} \ \Rightarrow\ d_{n-i} \geq n-i.$$
This is the condition for Chvatal's theorem, hence $G'$ contains a Hamiltonian circuit. Then by deleting $u$, G must contain a Hamiltonian path.

**Edit**
See [here](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0095895672900202/1-s2.0-0095895672900202-main.pdf?_tid=4c262b13-b045-4e69-999b-165770571323&acdnat=1548860686_f9ceaceaca96d50c964695897d44245f), p164-165 for a proof of Chvatal's theorem. This is a proof by contraposition. The key point is to take $G$ as maximal non-hamiltonian, i.e. the addition of any edge would make $G$ hamiltonian. Therefore $G$ must include an hamiltonian path (remember that hamiltonian = cyle, minus an edge = path). And then working on some maximal degree vertices, you reach the above inequalities

Comment: Can you explain what is the Chvatal's theorem proof? Also, is there any alternate proof for this?

Comment: I edited the post, with a link to the proof

Comment: Where do you get $d_i \le i-1$ from? In fact, isn't a cycle of length five, where $d_i=2$ for all $i$, self-complementary?

Comment: @FranciscoSantos I never claimed that. I'm saying that the graph satisfy the statement : `` **if** $d_i\leq i-1$ **then** $d_{n+1-i} \geq n-i$.  ''

This is sufficient to deduce that $G'$ satisfies Chvatal's theorem : for every $i\leq n/2$, either $d_i\geq i+1$ or $d_{n-i}\geq n-i$